# associate android app to file extension

Tags: android, file, manifest

I would like to associate my app to text file, so what i did is:

```
<data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
<data android:scheme="file" />
<data android:host="*" />
<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt" />
```

This works for abc.txt. However, when the file name is my.record.txt. It does not work.
I would like to handle file name with double dots. How should I change to handle this case?

Answer (score 0):

it is because,your file have double dots in fle name,change it **myrecord.txt** and then try to read a file.

according file naming, the file should have only single dot before the wxtension.

Comment: i know, but i want to support that, please advise on how to do so, thanks